# Correcting issue in slug of custom extension in config.yaml

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

Error message

```
(1/1) #1537298284 InvalidArgumentException
Enhancer type cannot be empty
```

I need to pass more than one argument to next page, how can I add more than more argument in config.yaml

This is my code:

```yaml
FakteSemilivevideolist:
    extension: FakteSemilivevideo
    plugin: FakteSemilivevideo
    routes:
      -
        routePath: '/{subuid}/{catuid}'
        _controller: 'Videodetails::list'
        _arguments:
          subuid: subuid
          catuid: catuid
    defaultController: 'Videodetails::list'
    defaults:
      subuid: '0'
      catuid: '0'
    requirements:
      subuid: '^[a-zA-Z0-9].*$'
      catuid: '^[a-zA-Z0-9].*$'
    aspects:
      subuid:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_faktesemilivevideo_domain_model_subcategory
        routeFieldName: uid
      catuid:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_faktesemilivevideo_domain_model_category
        routeFieldName: uid
```

Comment: Please post the code or error in question, not an image.

Comment: Please show the URL with all Get-parameters which you want to beautify.

Answer (score 0):

in your configuration the type of RouteEnhancer is missing (e.g. **type: Extbase**). Also says the error message: "Enhancer type cannot be empty".

Your configuration must look like this:

```yaml
FakteSemilivevideolist:
    type: Extbase
    extension: FakteSemilivevideo
    plugin: FakteSemilivevideo
    routes:
      -
        routePath: '/{subuid}/{catuid}'
        _controller: 'Videodetails::list'
        _arguments:
          subuid: subuid
          catuid: catuid
    defaultController: 'Videodetails::list'
    defaults:
      subuid: '0'
      catuid: '0'
    requirements:
      subuid: '^[a-zA-Z0-9].*$'
      catuid: '^[a-zA-Z0-9].*$'
    aspects:
      subuid:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_faktesemilivevideo_domain_model_subcategory
        routeFieldName: uid
      catuid:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_faktesemilivevideo_domain_model_category
        routeFieldName: uid
```

Kay